# Node.js: архитектура приложения с поддержкой плагинов

Tags: node.js

Хочу в своем приложении дать возможность написания плагинов сторонним разработчикам. Как это можно реализовать с учетом того что плагины могут обладать своими зависимостями. Возможно ли сделать так чтобы плагин не мог выбросить исключение, которое приведет к завершению приложения. Существуют ли вообще паттерны для реализации плагинов в node.js?

PS: Остановился на [architect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/architect). Само строит граф зависимостей и в нужной последовательности инициализирует модули. Все устраивает, от исключений, конечно, никто не застрахует.

Comment: *Возможно ли сделать так чтобы плагин не мог выбросить исключение, которое приведет к завершению приложения.* - да, try/catch

Comment: @etki попробуйте try/catch'ем поймать ассинхронщину...

Comment: @Suvitruf да просто обернуть сверху еще в promise

Comment: @etki вы каждый вызов методов плагина в промисы оборачивать собираетесь? )

Comment: @etki кстати, от SIG ERROR ваши промисы, try/catch'и не спасут.

Comment: @Suvitruf вопрос шашечек и езды